# Length or duration?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing a web application in which you can make bookings. When configuring a booking I need to know for how long the session will be. I'm wondering if the best word is length or duration?

Length: [100 minutes]

or

Duration: [100 minutes]

Or is there perhaps a better alternative?

Thanks!

Comment: Duration is a better choice

Comment: _Duration_ is equivalent to _length of time_. So if you use "length", you only _imply_ the time. In forms, or UI in general, it's usually a good idea to be as specific and explicit as possible, so _duration_ is better.

Comment: Duration.  But make sure that everyone are clear on whether the time is total time or running time.  Total time is the time from start to finish, the movie starts at 10:00 and ends at 11:45, so total time is 105 minutes.  But the running time of the movie itself is 95 minutes, and 10 minutes was the intermission.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either word can be used in this context, and they'll be understood perfectly well. *Duration* is more specific to lengths of time, so it might be more appropriate. On the other hand, *length* is a more familiar word; using *duration* makes it seem more proper or technical.

Comment: I agree with your answer, except the part that *duration* sounds "snobbish".  Unlike *length*, it also has the bonus of indicating that what is being measured is definitely *time*.

Comment: Maybe "technical" would be a better description.

Comment: Yes, "technical" is better!  I wanted to propose "accurate", but assuming your answer is correct, they are both accurate.  And I didn't want to sound "snobbish". ;) ;)

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Well, I'm trying to explain why it's not more common in casual conversation. Accuracy doesn't express that.

Answer (score 1):

Although you didn't ask about it, the previous answer correctly notes that duration isn't used for distance; from [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duration#Noun), *duration* means “An amount of time or a particular time interval” and “The time taken for the current situation to end, especially the current war”, plus a technical finance meaning (“A measure of the sensitivity of the price of a financial asset...”).

While you can use either of *duration* or *length* (see below), a shorter word you might consider is *term*. From [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/term#Noun), sense 11 is “Duration of a set length”.

Besides *length*'s primary sense “The measurement of distance along the longest dimension of an object”, [en.wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/length#Noun) mentions senses “duration” and (figuratively) “Total extent”.

Answer (score 0):

Opinion: Length be used to define distance or size ( length very commonly refers to physical size i.e., the length, width, and depth of an object) whereas duration measures time period.

Length is also used to define time period, as in: 
How long have you been waiting?

So, while length may be used for either, duration should not be used for distance.